# SPARQL Query the triples created using Protégé ontological approach for distinct classes with object properties

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology, protege

I have a question about querying the object properties that can be defined between classes.I have created triples using the protege ontological approach where,I have created two classes named "A" and "B" with instances A1, A2, A3, and B1, B2, and B3 respectively.

I have added an object property "aToB". Now I want to write a Query that can query the instances under each class using the object property.for which I have written the following QUERY

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  : <http://www.semanticweb.org/arash>
SELECT ?x ?y
    WHERE { ?x :AtoB ?y}
```

however, upon doing this procedure nothing is returned can you tell me what is the issue?

[image: Defining classes in Protoge]
[image: Defing the object property between Class A and B]
[image: SPARQL query written]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am adding the TTL code:

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/arash#> .
@prefix ab: <http://www.semanticweb.org/arash#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/arash> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/arash> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/arash#aToB
ab:aToB rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
        owl:inverseOf ab:bToA ;
        rdfs:domain ab:A ;
        rdfs:range ab:B .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/arash#bToA
ab:bToA rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/arash#A
ab:A rdf:type owl:Class .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/arash#B
ab:B rdf:type owl:Class .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/arash#A1
ab:A1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
               ab:A ;
      ab:aToB ab:A1 .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/arash#A2
ab:A2 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
               ab:A ;
      ab:aToB ab:B2 .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/arash#A3
ab:A3 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
               ab:A .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/arash#B1
ab:B1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
               ab:B ;
      ab:aToB ab:A1 .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/arash#B2
ab:B2 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
               ab:B .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/arash#B3
ab:B3 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
               ab:B ;
      ab:aToB ab:A3 ;
      owl:topDataProperty "" .


[ ab:aToB ab:A1
] .

###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

Comment: and where did you add which instance of `A` is connected to which instance of `B`? I mean, neither a reasoner nor the SPARQL query engine can guess the data

Comment: @UninformedUser, thank you for going through the model, I have added the object property assertations to the model. I have now added the complete images and the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix in your query is missing the closing #.

Comment: yes indeed it works now, thank you very much I had been breaking my head over it for the past two weeks, kudos to you.